# Why can't I access a specific key in React using Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

In React, I have a prop called firebase that carries over an object that contains auth and then I can visually see in console it has a key called currentUser. When I try to access that key it's then undefined:

console.log(this.props.firebase.auth)

This shows:

```
Yl {m: false, settings: Nk, app: FirebaseAppImpl, b: Dh, N: Array(5), …}
C: null
G: []
Ha: ƒ ()
I: [ƒ]
...
currentUser: Q {G: Array(0), m: "xxx-eM", o: "[DEFAULT]", u: "xxx.firebaseapp.com", b: Dh, …}
...
```

However, when I then go:

```
console.log(this.props.firebase.auth.currentUser)
```

I just get `undefined`

What may be causing this behavior?

Comment: can u update your code and show us how you are passing the firebase as prop to your component?

Comment: the correct way to access is `this.props.firebase.auth().currentUser` [see docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)

Comment: Unfortunately I get this.props.firebase.auth() is not a function from this

Comment: it's hard to say when we don't see the full code.

Comment: if your firebase property comes from firebase object and it's properly set, it should work....you're probably missing something. [see this article to see how to setup your code properly](https://medium.com/@wcandillon/integrating-firebase-authentication-with-react-router-in-react-16-3-92f53b67c0b0)